# Formtastic array inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a a serializable field on my rails model that allows arrays.

Question is, in formtastic, how would I get the output:

```
<input type="text" name="model[variables][]" />
```

I'll tell it the value, im not worried about that.

Answer (score 4):

As i know, formtastic can't generate text inputs for array values. And this is not a formtastic issue.

How would the list of text values look like(labels, validation errors etc.)? As a list of checkboxes? - then use

```
f.input :authors, :as => :check_boxes, 
        :collection => current_user.company.users.active
```

Your concern is probably the name of each input because it reflects to request 'params'.
It is possible to implement custom formtastic field type or simply use Rails helpers to achieve what you need.

E.g. pass array as a hidden value:

```
= semantic_form_for @model do |form|
  - @model.variables.each do |value|
    = hidden_field_tag 'model[variable][]', value, id: "model_variable_#{value}"
```

Then you will have params[:model][:variables] to be an array.